# i have get the ajax responce in javascript but now i want submit the form and want that ajax respone also in my POST array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to add data in database for that i want the ajax responce array also in the POST array but havent do that

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Campus Accreditation</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <?php Web_Interface::load_accreditation($obj_admin->adminCountry); ?>
    <script>
      jQuery("input[id=accreditation]").click(function() {
        var selectedCheckBoxArray = new Array();
        var n = jQuery("input[id=accreditation]:checked").length;
        if (n > 0) {
          jQuery("input[id=accreditation]:checked").each(function() {
            selectedCheckBoxArray.push($(this).val());
          });
          //send check box data value array to server using Ajax
          var data = {
            myCheckboxes: selectedCheckBoxArray
          };
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: "../process/ProcessAjaxChecking.php",
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
              $('#getAcademics').html(data);
              $json = json_encode(data);
              $.ajax({
                url: "Example.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                  $('#getAcademics').html(data);
                }
              });
            }
          });

        }
      });
    </script>
  </div>
```

**Before Submit Form**
[image]

**After submit From**
[image]

Comment: Is value.php your php script file where you are trying to get your request data?

Comment: postValue.php is file where i just check the AJAX POST ARRAY

Answer (score 0):

In your value.php you have given name 'academicsCheckBoxes`and you have paased in ajax`myCheckboxes`.

**Change**

```
var data = {
    academicsCheckBoxes: selectedCheckBoxArray 
};
```

**Updated Code**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="focusedinput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Campus Accreditation</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <?php Web_Interface::load_accreditation($obj_admin->adminCountry); ?>
    <script>
      jQuery("input[id=accreditation]").click(function() {
        var selectedCheckBoxArray = new Array();
        var n = jQuery("input[id=accreditation]:checked").length;
        if (n > 0) {
          jQuery("input[id=accreditation]:checked").each(function() {
            selectedCheckBoxArray.push($(this).val());
          });
          //send check box data value array to server using Ajax
          var data = {
            academicsCheckBoxes: selectedCheckBoxArray 
          };
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: "../process/ProcessAjaxChecking.php",
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
              $('#getAcademics').html(data);
              $json = json_encode(data);
              $.ajax({
                url: "Example.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                  $('#getAcademics').html(data);
                }
              });
            }
          });

        }
      });
    </script>
  </div>
```

Comment: <?php


if ($_POST['AcademicsCheckBoxes']) {
    echo "done";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
}
?>

Comment: this is the postValue.php

Comment: but this postValue.php have not anny connect with this bro

Comment: have no Connection *

Comment: but you are getting error in postValue.php and you have highlighted it.

Comment: `<?php if ($_POST['AcademicsCheckBoxes']) { echo "done"; echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>"; } ?>` this code giving you error so just put isset() to check post values. Correct code is : `<?php if (isset($_POST['AcademicsCheckBoxes'])) { echo "done"; echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>"; } ?>` replace this with your code. @HusnainAli